# if statement that detects firefox and returns another link to another page with code compatible for firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have created a website that looks good on IE and Chrome but on Firefox the navigation bar is too wide and it is blocking my header. So, I am wondering, how do I write an "if statement" that can detect the browser if it is Firefox and then if the browser is Firefox, it will return the code for a different page that is written to be compatible with Firefox (namely, I would like to rewrite the code for the navigation bar and make it a link to this same page if the browser turns up to be Firefox). If someone could please let me know, that would be great. I am trying to do this using JavaScript but am not sure how to write this.

Basically, I am trying to write this:

if (browser is firefox)

then return a link to another page (code rewritten to be compatible with firefox)

otherwise, if browser is not firefox, leave the code as it is.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't used a css normalizer to make sure all browser defaults are the same. The idea of different pages for different browsers sounds like a really bad one

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1){
   return firefoxLink;
}
```

OR:

```
if (/firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    return firefoxLink;
}
```

But I suggest you to prevent from doing this thing.
If you do it, you may do something wrong.

If it's Explorer, it's OK ;-)

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I am right now using Bootstrap. I am wondering, is css normalizer in Bootstrap? If not,  should I use this in my code to fix the above problem? Thank you again.

Comment: You don't need to use the code above.
I think there is better solution and not hack..

Please send me your code and I'll try to help (jsfiddle/codepen)..